# Google drive download not working code error

Tags: python, download

Hey not sure why this is not working. My code downloads a file from my google drive and then puts it in a specific directory. Don't no why is happening please help

error

[image]

```
import os
import requests
def download(url):
    directory = 'C:\Users\IEUser\AppData\Roaming'
    name = url.split("/")[-1]
    file_name = os.path.join(directory, name)
    get_response = requests.get(url)
    with open(file_name, "wb") as out_file:
        out_file.write(get_response.content)

download('http://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1A2Q3C2VN_8d3AHuNnWX0ZGFmhaeNHNL8&export=download')
```

Answer (score 0):

The file name calculated by `name = url.split("/")[-1]` will contain a `?` what is not allowed on windows. Consider removing or replacing the `?` from `name` variable or even extracting and using the `id` parameter value from the url as the file name.

In order to verify that in the first step, set `name` to a static value like `test-download`

Comment: What does that mean exactly here do you see the ? .

Comment: Your url is `http://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1A2Q3C2VN_8d3AHuNnWX0ZGFmhaeNHNL8&export=download` made of the protocoll (http), host (drive.google.com), path (/u/0/uc) and two request params (id, export) introduced by ? and separated by &. I'm referring to the ? introducing the params.

Comment: Okay thanks guys I now know what the ? means now but how can I fix this??

Comment: Set name to a fixed value for example or extract the id out of the url (all the chars in between id= and &)

Comment: import os
import requests
def download(url):
    directory = 'C:\Users\IEUser\AppData\Roaming'
    name = url.split("/")[-1]
    file_name = os.path.join(directory, name)
    get_response = requests.get(url)
    with open(file_name, "wb") as out_file:
        out_file.write(get_response.content)

download('http://drive.google.com/u/0/ucid=&export=download')

Comment: like that ??? could please show me how to do it i'm very new to python